# HTTP GET too big for buffer

Tags: http, get, http-headers, arduino

Hello. I am using this example from cooking hacks to make a HTTP GET call to my server.(bottom of the page)

http://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/arduino-3g-gprs-gsm-gps

My end goal would be to get one word from a php page to my Arduino Uno.

But I am running in to problems because my Arduino has a limited buffer and the header size is bigger than its buffer.

- My header size is 363
- And my download size is 12
- The max size is 64

Because of this my code is not working. I want to only get the 12 but don't know how to do this I hope someone can help me point me in the right direction.

```
*  Description: This example shows how to do a GET method. So the buffer of   
*  is limited, we recommend to use the GET method with short answer for the
*  requested webs. 
*  This example shows the AT commands (and the answers of the module) used
*  to work with HTTP. For more information about the AT commands, 
*  refer to the AT command manual.
*
*  Copyright (C) 2013 Libelium Comunicaciones Distribuidas S.L.
*  http://www.libelium.com
*
*  This program is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify 
*  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by 
*  the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or 
*  (at your option) any later version. 
*  
*  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, 
*  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of 
*  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the 
*  GNU General Public License for more details. 
*  
*  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License 
*  along with this program.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>. 
*
*  Version 0.2
*  Author: Alejandro Gallego 
*/


int8_t answer;
int onModulePin = 2, aux;
int data_size = 0;
int end_file = 0;

char aux_str[100];

char data[250];
int x = 0;
long previous;

char url[ ]="rubenvandijk.com";
int port= 80;
char request[ ]="GET /misc/twittertest5/get_tweet.php HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:    rubenvandijk.com\r\n";



void setup(){

pinMode(onModulePin, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(115200);   

Serial.println("Starting...");
power_on();

delay(3000);

// sets the PIN code
sendATcommand("AT+CPIN=0000", "OK", 2000);

delay(3000);

while( (sendATcommand("AT+CREG?", "+CREG: 0,1", 500) || 
    sendATcommand("AT+CREG?", "+CREG: 0,5", 500)) == 0 );

// sets APN, user name and password
sendATcommand("AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,\"IP\",\"prepaidinternet\"", "OK", 2000);
sendATcommand("AT+CSOCKAUTH=1,1,\"\",\"\"", "OK", 2000);




}
void loop(){

// request the url
sprintf(aux_str, "AT+CHTTPACT=\"%s\",%d", url, port);
answer = sendATcommand(aux_str, "+CHTTPACT: REQUEST", 60000);

if (answer == 1)
{        
    Serial.println(request);
    //Serial.println(host);
    //Serial.println("Content-Length: 0");
    // Sends <Ctrl+Z>
    aux_str[0] = 0x1A;
    aux_str[1] = 0x00;
    answer = sendATcommand(aux_str, "+CHTTPACT: DATA,", 60000);

    x=0;
    do{
        if (answer == 1)
        {
            data_size = 0;
            while(Serial.available()==0);
            aux = Serial.read();
            do{
                data_size *= 10;
                data_size += (aux-0x30);
                while(Serial.available()==0);
                aux = Serial.read();        
            }
            while(aux != 0x0D);

            Serial.print("Data received: ");
            Serial.println(data_size);





            if (data_size > 0)
            {
                while(Serial.available() < data_size);
                Serial.read();


                for (int y = 0; y < data_size; y++)
                {
                    data[x] = Serial.read();
                    x++;
                }
                data[x] = '\0';
            }
            else
            {
                Serial.println("Download finished");    
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("Error getting the url");
            data_size = 0;
        }

        answer = sendATcommand2("", "+CHTTPACT: DATA,", "+CHTTPACT:0", 20000);

    }while (answer != 1);

    if (answer == 2)
    {
        Serial.print("Data received hallo:");
        Serial.println(data);
    }
    else
    {
        Serial.println("Error getting data");
    }
}
else
{
    Serial.println("Error waiting the request");    
}

delay(10000);

}

void power_on(){

uint8_t answer=0;

// checks if the module is started
answer = sendATcommand("AT", "OK", 2000);
if (answer == 0)
{
    // power on pulse
    digitalWrite(onModulePin,HIGH);
    delay(3000);
    digitalWrite(onModulePin,LOW);

    // waits for an answer from the module
    while(answer == 0){    
        // Send AT every two seconds and wait for the answer
        answer = sendATcommand("AT", "OK", 2000);    
    }
}

}


int8_t sendATcommand(char* ATcommand, char* expected_answer1,
        unsigned int timeout)
{

uint8_t x=0,  answer=0;
char response[100];
unsigned long previous;

memset(response, '\0', 100);    // Initialize the string

delay(100);

while( Serial.available() > 0) Serial.read();    // Clean the input buffer

Serial.println(ATcommand);    // Send the AT command 


x = 0;
previous = millis();

// this loop waits for the answer
do{

    if(Serial.available() != 0){    
        response[x] = Serial.read();
        x++;
        // check if the desired answer is in the response of the module
        if (strstr(response, expected_answer1) != NULL)    
        {
            answer = 1;
        }
    }
    // Waits for the asnwer with time out
}
while((answer == 0) && ((millis() - previous) < timeout));    

return answer;
}

int8_t sendATcommand2(char* ATcommand, char* expected_answer1,
     char* expected_answer2, unsigned int timeout)
{

uint8_t x=0,  answer=0;
char response[100];
unsigned long previous;

memset(response, '\0', 100);    // Initialize the string

delay(100);

while( Serial.available() > 0) Serial.read();    // Clean the input buffer

Serial.println(ATcommand);    // Send the AT command 


x = 0;
previous = millis();

// this loop waits for the answer
do{


    if(Serial.available() != 0){    
        response[x] = Serial.read();
        x++;
        // check if the desired answer is in the response of the module
        if (strstr(response, expected_answer1) != NULL)    
        {
            answer = 1;
        }
        // check if the desired answer is in the response of the module
        if (strstr(response, expected_answer2) != NULL)    
        {
            answer = 2;
        }
    }
    // Waits for the asnwer with time out
}
while((answer == 0) && ((millis() - previous) < timeout));    

return answer;
}
```

It now returns

```
�Starting...
AT
AT+CPIN=0000
AT+CREG?
AT+CGSOCKCONT=1,"IP","prepaidinternet"
AT+CSOCKAUTH=1,1,"",""
AT+CHTTPACT="rubenvandijk.com",80
GET /misc/twittertest5/get_tweet.php HTTP/1.1
Host: rubenvandijk.com
Data received: 524
```

It gets stuck at

```
if (data_size > 0)
            {
                while(Serial.available() < data_size);
                Serial.read();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have several ideas you can try...

1) Process your incoming data one line at a time, don't buffer it all up to process.
2) Add some special characters to your web server response, toss all the data until you see that character or sequence.  Say add a # symbol in front of the data you want, as bytes come in only buffer up those after the #.
3) use a circular buffer and let it overwrite till all the data is received, leaving you the last X bytes in the buffer, process by working backwards from the buffer tail.

Number 1 is the best answer, number 2 is the easiest.

Comment: Number two sounds good enough for my purposes could you elaborate a bite more on how to do this? I don't have a great deal of experience in this script language. So I only know how tot ad the # to my php hahaha which won't get me very far. Any words for me to google or an example code I can try out?